# Material-UI CardMedia image not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've applied the styling on to CardMedia but the image still doesn't show

```
<CardMedia 
    style = {{ height: 0, paddingTop: '56.25%'}}
    image={thread.url}
    title={thread.title}
/>
```

thread.url is just a link to the image, so I believe it should be working 
Am I doing it correctly or is there a different way to show the image?

Answer (score 3):

If you use create-reac-app it means you probably also use Webpack. Webpack requires you to specify all dpendencies using:

```
import imageUrl from './image.jpg'
```

And then you can use it as following:

```
image={imageUrl}
```

You can find more information about using Webpack with Create React App 
[here](https://www.fullstackreact.com/p/using-webpack-with-create-react-app/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I added style and **set height** for image and CardMedia started working. Additionally I put my images in public folder but it is working also with external links.

```
  <CardMedia
    style={{ height: "250px", paddingTop: "2%" }}
    component="img"
    image={"/pancakes.jpg"}
    title="Picture"
    alt="pic"
  />
```