# Material UI CardMedia is not showing images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using CardMedia to display images on the screen but it is not showing it.

**I have gone through the similar question on Stack Overflow. There the solution give is to import the image and then use it. But here I'm fetching image url from backend using API call.**

I have also tried changng heights but it didn't work.

Can anyone explain what is the issue?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%",
  },
}));

function ProductList(props) {
  const [productList, setProductList] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const url = `https://api.growcify.com/dev/product/list/${props.listId}`;

  const getList = () => {
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setProductList(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, []);

  return !loading ? (
    productList.length > 0 ? (
      productList.map((list) => (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>{list.name}</CardContent>
          {list.photos.map((img) => {
            img !== null && (
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                {console.log(img)}
                <CardMedia
                  image={img}
                  component="img"
                  title="Some title"
                  className={classes.media}
                />
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Card>
      ))
    ) : (
      <h2>No Data Available </h2>
    )
  ) : (
    <CircularProgress />
  );
}

export default ProductList;
```

In the provided Screenshot, You can see in the console that I'm getting image url but image is not showing there.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-UI CardMedia image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389006/material-ui-cardmedia-image-not-showing)

Comment: No... I saw it... And i tried..

Comment: i think image not getting you can relative path for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Remove height: 0, from media style
```

Comment: Did... I even tried to change the height. But still it is not showing

Comment: try to debug using an image from some  public url

Comment: can you see that image when you tried that url from your browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
image={"http://localhost:3000/yourPath/"+this.state.your-data.your-variable name}
```

- 

Dont forget to padding top
Tell me if it works :D