# React CardMedia URL images not loading

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

React MaterialUI component - CardMedia does not show the image when we provide a URL to the given
prop - image={imageURL}

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  sx={{
    height: 140
  }}
  image={imageLink}
  alt={imageLink.split("/")[4]}
/>
```

[image: Output-Image]

A few examples for the CardMedia Docs are presented here - [CardMedia Code Examples](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/)
but none showed a CardMedia using an image source given by a URL.

The previous question asked did not resolve the issue - [Material-UI CardMedia image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389006/material-ui-cardmedia-image-not-showing)

Comment: Please share your code example on codesandbox, So I can check How are you passing image path link and all other stuff.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactcardmedia-url-forked-m5jtz9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A23%2C47

Check this code-sandbox link, i have tried the same, and i am able to view the image

Comment: This is the URL, I have double checked - https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Images/making-new-components-intro.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. It is a CORS issue.
I am only using the frontend and the web pack is serving the bundle. I am not using the Create React App. It's my own custom-configured frontend-only app and for development, I am using webpack dev server.

However, after knowing the issue, and adding the appropriate headers to allow it in Content-Security-Policy, the images are still not appearing.

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; img-src 'self' https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/* data:;",
            'X-Custom-Header': 'MyHeaderValue',      
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx|js)$/,
            use: ['ts-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('./src/assets/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.jpg" />
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; media-src 'self' https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com">

    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Meta Tag"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    
    <title>Some Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `img` as `component` then you have to use src={imageLink}

but the working way is as below:

**React js**

```
<CardMedia sx={{ height: 140 }} >
    <img image={imageLink} alt={imageLink.split("/")[4]} />
</CardMedia>
```

**Next js**

```
import Image from 'next/image';


<CardMedia component="img" sx={{ height: 140 }} >
    <Image src={imageLink} alt={imageLink.split("/")[4]} />
</CardMedia>
```

That's it.

Comment: if an image tag if used so why needs to import CardMedia?

Comment: That is for Next JS. Because it's not working after building the Next Js app.

Comment: nope! CardMedia is used for media not to add extra **img** tags neither in next nor in react

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is with the provided media URL.
Try this and check the error log.

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  height="194"
  image="https://www.example.com/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
  alt="Paella dish"
  onError={(e) => {
    console.error("Error loading image:", e.target.src);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried using your URL and hardcoded your provided URL, still not working. 
![Hardcoded-URL](https://imgur.com/a/xEzDCnN)

Answer (score 0):

`https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactcardmedia-url-forked-m5jtz9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js`

Check this code-sandbox link, i have tried the same, and i am able to view the image

```
import "./styles.css";
import { CardMedia } from "@mui/material";

const styles = {
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%", // 16:9,
    marginTop: "30",
  },
};

const imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <CardMedia
        image={imageUrl} // require image
        title="Contemplative Reptile"
        style={styles.media} // specify styles
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function App() {
  let imageURL =
    "https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Images/making-new-components-intro.jpg";
  return (
    <>
      <DummyComponent imageURL="https://dars-portfolio.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Images/making-new-components-intro.jpg" />
      <h1>
        
        to passing props or set as a variable. Both condition has been
        satisfied.
      </h1>
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
        <CardMedia sx={{ height: 240 }} image={imageURL} title="react" />
        
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

function DummyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
        <CardMedia sx={{ height: 240 }} image={props.imageURL} title="react" />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            PASSING AS A REACT PROPS
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Props stand for properties. They are read-only values that can be
            passed across components to display relevant data in your
            React apps.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small">Share</Button>
          <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

- Maybe you are missing something. You haven't shown the minimal code
  which is necessary to find out the error or bug.
- Props passes image URL **or** image URL uses simple a variable. The below link satisfied both conditions.
- [React CardMedia URL
  image is loading](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/recursing-agnesi-9jgz5y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)